# "Framework not found" after attaching the updated framework

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-frameworks

I have created a framework and using that in my app. There was one change which I made in the framework. I built it again and from the Debug-iphonesimulator folder, I copied it (MyFramework.framework) and replaced the one I was using that in the app. On building the app, I got the error :

> ld: framework not found MyFramework
>   clang: error: linker command
>   failed with exit code 1

This happened only when I build the framework and replaced it in the app. Otherwise the framework was working fine before.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your application target and delete and re-add (MyFramework.framework) inside Embedded Binaries section. Also check its added in Linked Frameworks and Libraries section. Go to build setting of app target and add path of the framework in Framework Search Paths.

Comment: If that was the case, it won't have worked at the first time. Still, I did what you mentioned. Does not work.

Comment: Are you adding your framework in application root folder? what path are you providing inside framework search path?

Comment: Not in the root folder. The search path is same as the framework location.